# Can't run apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I just installed macbuntu and i cant install any package an i keep getting the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mricron
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get update` `and im getting the error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.239.18.173 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can i fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your installation of Ubuntu 11.04 has reached end of life, so you can no longer update it or install packages from the default Ubuntu repositories. I strongly recommend installing a supported version of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 14.04 is a Long Term Support release that will be supported by updates until April, 2019.

Ubuntu 14.04 has different systems requirements than Ubuntu 11.04. Your computer should have at least 768MB RAM, preferably 2GB RAM for decent performance.

You can download Ubuntu 14.04 from the official [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) webpage. After you have installed Ubuntu 14.04, you can customize it to get that collection of Mac-like skins and themes that you currently have by installing the [MBuntu Transformation pack for Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/11/mbuntu-macbuntu-1410-transformation.html). The theme of the MBuntu Transformation pack for Ubuntu 14.04 resembles  Mac OS X Yosemite.